# Update button text on click

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I created a command:

```xml
<command
      id="disableOrEnableCommand"
      name="Disable or Enable Command">
</command>
```

Then I added a button to the toolbar:

```xml
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
   <menuContribution
         allPopups="false"
         locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
         <toolbar
            id="disableOrEnable">
            <command
               commandId="disableOrEnableCommand"
               label="Disable Me"
               style="push">
         </command>
      </toolbar>
   </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

The next step was binding the command to a handler:

```xml
<extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
    <handler
        class="DisableOrEnableHandler"
        commandId="disableOrEnableCommand">
    </handler>
</extension>
```

I configured the handler to implement `IHandler` and `IElementUpdater`( because I want to update the button text):

```java
public class DisableOrEnableHandler implements IHandler, IElementUpdater{

    public boolean isEnabled = true;

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        isEnabled = !isEnabled;
        // Trigger somehow the updateElement() method
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateElement(UIElement element, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map parameters) {
        if ( isEnabled) {
            element.setText("Disable me");
        } else {
            element.setText("Enable me");
        }
    }

    // other overriden methods from IHandler and IElementUpdater
}
```

I am missing one piece of the puzzle, how can I configure the button to trigger the updateElement when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `ICommandService.refreshElements` call to call update elements. In the handler you can use something like:

```java
IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);

ICommandService commandService = window.getService(ICommandService.class);

commandService.refreshElements(event.getCommand().getId(), null);
```

(code abstracted from `org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.PinEditorHandler`)